# WordPress plugin Elementor not working with custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

When trying to edit with Elementor on my website I get, **"The preview could not be loaded" "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Click on 'Learn more' and follow each of the steps to quickly solve it."**

I have tried looking at the steps it provided but that didn't help.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your theme uses the function `the_content()`